# HTMLFieldValus of the ListItem

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am reading the values of the List using CSOM. Some List items contains **double quotes** in the field values. When I read the its value double quotes are replaced by **& quot;** .  How can I get the value displayed in the List?[image]

```
string siteCollectionUrl = "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename";
string userName = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "yourpassword";

// Namespace: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client  
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteCollectionUrl);

// Namespace: System.Security
SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
password.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);

// Namespace: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client  
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, secureString);

// Namespace: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client  
Site site = ctx.Site;

ctx.Load(site);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Web web = ctx.Web;

ctx.Load(web,w => w.ServerRelativeUrl,w => w.Lists);

List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("List1");

ctx.Load(list);
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
ListItemCollection itemColl = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

ctx.Load(itemColl);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (ListItem item in itemColl)

{
    Console.WriteLine(item["Title"].ToString());
    foreach (var fieldValue in item.FieldValuesAsHtml.FieldValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fieldValue.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(fieldValue.Value);//double quotes are replaced by &quot; 
        //eg. Check for "Continue demo.." button. is getting as
        //Check for &quot;Continue demo..&quot; button.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354(v=vs.110).aspx) method to decode the Html encoded strings and get the actual values as displayed in the List.

```
using System.Net;


foreach (ListItem item in itemColl)

{
    Console.WriteLine(item["Title"].ToString());
    foreach (var fieldValue in item.FieldValuesAsHtml.FieldValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fieldValue.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(fieldValue.Value));
    }
}
```

you can also replace all `&quot;` with `"` but that would only replace double quotes and if there are any other html encodes like `&gt; &lt;` above code will take care of it.